# Group by Column in Dataframe and create seperate csv for each group

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge csv file of 1 GB which contains records of each day .Example like below

```
Date        orderquantity

2015-06-19   23
2015-06-19   30
2015-06-20   33
2015-06-20   40
```

So record is present of each and everyday ,is there a efficient  way in Python Pandas data frame where I can group the data according to date and  then store it as a seperate csv for each date .

My output result for above example would be

```
  CSV 1 
Date           orderquantity
2015-06-19      23
2015-06-19      30

CSV 2
 Date           orderquantity
 2015-06-20     33
 2015-06-20     40
```

Will I have to like sort/group by date in the data frame and then have a for loop and iterate through the entire data frame ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for name, group in df.groupby('Date'):
    group.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(name), index=False)
```

Comment: the groupby clause gives error ValueError: No axis named 2 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: I assumed your first column was a date.  My apologies.